# Preferred approach for making the `{targets}` R package detect changes to functions and exported datasets from my own developed R data package

Tags: r, targets-r-package

I am a beginner with the `{targets}` package, and I was wondering what is the right setup to register dependencies to functions (and datasets) developed by myself in an R data package.

My idea is to use `{targets}` to develop the somewhat involved workflow of generating several exported datasets, and files on disk, for this hypothetical R data package of mine: `{MyRDataPackage}`. And I would like those functions that generate these datasets/files to `data-raw/` to be exported functions from the package itself, i.e. I would rather not have them sourced (as in `source("R/functions.R")`) in `_targets.R`.

By reading from [Chapter 6.3 Dependencies](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/practices.html#dependencies) , I got the feeling I could take this approach:

```
# _targets.R
tar_option_set(envir = getNamespace("MyRDataPackage"))
```

but reading a bit further, namely in [Chapter 6.5 Packages-based invalidation](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/practices.html#packages-based-invalidation), it seems I could also pass my `{MyRDataPackage`} to the `imports` argument:

```
# _targets.R
tar_option_set(
  packages = c("MyRDataPackage"),
  imports = c("MyRDataPackage")
)
```

So my question is: is either approach is fine? Or, are there reasons to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guidance in Section 6.5 is the current recommendation. 6.3 is outdated but was just updated in https://github.com/ropensci-books/targets/commit/a9661e642beb174383222af16c1a599ae10a4735. Also answered at [https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/586\#discussioncomment-1140345](https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/586%5C#discussioncomment-1140345).